# OpenLayers GetFeature loading indicator

Tags: openlayers-2, geoext, getfeature

I need to set up loadMask for `OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature`. I know I should hide the mask on featureselected event or on protocol callback but when should I show the mask?

Here is code (assume I have _mask global variable with show and hide methods):

```
var selectionControl = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
            protocol: this.map.layerUtils.createWFSProtocol({featureType:featureType, srsName:'EPSG:'+ this.map.projectionCode}),
            clickout:true,
            box: true,
            toggleKey: "ctrlKey"
        });

selectionControl.events.register("featureselected", this, function(e) {
            _mask.hide();
        });
```